# Chrome textbox losing focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hi I have an web application written in angular.  I am seeing a strange bug in Chrome which I cannot replicate in IE (its usually the other way round)

I have a input textbox of type number - when I type more that 2 characters the cursor loses focus and I have to click back into it to keep typing.  The same thing is happening when try and delete from the text box.

So if I want to enter 1000 for example.

I type 10 then textbox loses focus. I then have to click the textbox enter the 2nd zero - focus gets lost again and then have to click in it again and enter the last zero.  If I want to delete this back to 10.  I delete last zero focus gets lost and have to click back into the textbox to delete the 2nd zero.

I cannot figure out what is causing this.

the rendered markup for the text is as below:

```
<td class="right-align muted ng-scope">
            <input name="txtTotal" type="number" min="0" max="99999" ng-model="item.Total" ng-bind="item.Total | number: 2" ng-change="updateTotal(item)" onkeydown="return isNumberKeyAndDecimal(event, 2, 5)" style="width:150px" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-touched">
        </td>
```

I thought it may have been the code in onkeydown - I can paste this function if required however I removed the onkeydown from the code did a hard refresh of the page and the error still happens (and the code as above works in IE)

Has anyone seen this behaviour before or got any pointers as too what the cause or fix may be?

Comment: Does it work with regular number inputs that don't have an `ng-model` bound to them?

Comment: Does the bug persist if you remove the `ng-bind` directive?

Comment: Will check and confirm

Comment: @RobertAKARobin - it works as expected for a regular input - this is in a bootstrap modal by the way if that would make any difference - I cant in reality remove the angular directives around the input

Comment: @Lex - no it works without that directive but i cant really remove it?

Comment: You are using `ng-bind` to format the value in the input? Maybe you can format on blur instead.